# input() в sublime text

Tags: python, sublime-text

Всем привет!
Только недавно начал изучать Python.
Приступая к изучению "ввода данных и цикла while", первое что я увидел было:

> «ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ Sublime Text и многие другие текстовые редакторы не
> запускают программы, запрашивающие входные данные у пользователя. Вы
> можете использовать эти редакторы для создания таких программ, но
> запускать их придется из терминального окна.»

Sublime мне крайне "зашел", попробовал PyCharm и VS Code - пока тяжело для восприятия.
Простого решения, как сделать Sublime работоспособным я не нашел.

Помогите, пожалуйста, и объясните на пальцах - что нужно установить в Sublime, чтобы я продолжил изучать язык и не пересаживался на другое ПО.

Answer (score 0):

В Sublime ничего устанавливать не нужно да и нечего, у него нет встроенного интерпретатора. Вы с ним прекрасно можете начинать изучение Python. Данное примечание говорит лишь о том, что запускать свой код вы сможете только из консоли.